# Why can't a sub access dynamic variables when used in a "return"ed map in raku?

Tags: raku, subroutine, dynamic-variables, rakudo

It seems that a a `sub` cannot access dynamic variables when it is used inside a map and that map is "return"ed.

Consider this piece of code:

```
sub start {
    my $*something = 'foobar';
    
    # WORKS
    say 'first say-something:';
    say-something;
    
    # WORKS
    say 'mapped say-something, no return:';
    my @foo = (^2).map({say-something});
    
    # ERROR: Dynamic variable $*something not found
    say 'mapped say-something, with return:';
    return (^2).map({say-something});
}

sub say-something {
    say $*something;
    1
}

start;
```

This will output:

```
first say-something:
foobar
mapped say-something, no return:
foobar
foobar
mapped say-something, with return:

Dynamic variable $*something not found
  in sub say-something at main.raku line 18
  in block <unit> at main.raku line 14
```

Why can't the sub access the dynamic variable? Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Routine [`map`](https://docs.raku.org/routine/map) is *lazy*, so the block is not run until after *start* has returned.

From the documentation:

> ```
> multi method map(Hash:D \hash)
> multi method map(Iterable:D \iterable)
> multi method map(|c)
> multi method map(\SELF: &block;; :$label, :$item)
> multi sub map(&code, +values)
> ```
>
> Examples applied to lists are included here for the purpose of
> illustration.
>
> For a list, it invokes *&code* for each element and gathers the return
> values in a sequence and returns it. This happens lazily, i.e. *&code*
> is only invoked when the return values are accessed.

So in your case, the map is evaluated once *start* returns, thus the dynamic variable is already out of scope.

A workaround for this is to force the `map` to happen *eagerly* by adding `.eager`

```
return (^2).map({say-something}).eager
```